# Simple sort verification for unit testing an ORDER BY?

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, sorting, ienumerable

I'm working on a DAL method that uses an ORDER BY clause in a SELECT.  The return value from the method is an `IEnumerable<T>`, where T is a class that encapsulates a domain entity, and the sort order would be based on one of the properties of this class, namely, "Priority."  It's important that this ORDER BY works, of course, so I want to write a sort verification into the unit test for this method.  Does anyone have a quick and simple algorithm for testing the order of an `IEnumerable<T>` based on one of the properties of T?  Is there something LINQ-y that I can use?

```
var items = repository.GetItems(true);   //true tells it to use the ORDER BY
items.ToList().ForEach(i => Assert.IsTrue(??What happens here??));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @nawfal, is it a duplicate if this question was asked before the proposed duplicate?

Comment: @AJ.Yes, [that is the policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=closing+older+question+with+newer+duplicate), though quite unfortunate. In fact there is a better option of *merging*. I will flag for moderator attention. Thanks!