# How to check if a list is ordered?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, list, html-lists

I am doing some unit tests and I want to know if there's any way to test if a list is ordered by a property of the objects it contains.

Right now I am doing it this way but I don't like it, I want a better way. Can somebody help me please?

```
// (fill the list)
List<StudyFeedItem> studyFeeds = 
    Feeds.GetStudyFeeds(2120, DateTime.Today.AddDays(-200), 20);   

StudyFeedItem previous = studyFeeds.First();

foreach (StudyFeedItem item in studyFeeds)
{
    if (item != previous)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(previous.Date > item.Date);
    }

    previous = item;
}
```

Comment: Be careful that you're not testing things that don't need to be tested. Are you ensuring that the query contains the expected order by clause, or are you merely checking to see that the order by clause works? The latter is wasteful.

Comment: @Chris - this is a good point (+1), and I wondered the same thing when I was asking the question.  Why would you say that testing the order by is wasteful?  Should I then simply trust the DB engine and the CLR to keep things straight?

Comment: @PITADev: Yes, you should absolutely trust that the DB engine and the CLR keep things straight. You're not testing that `int x = 2, y = 2, z = x + y` has `Assert.IsTrue(z == 4)'` succeed are you? You should unit test the behavior of your public methods and nothing more. So if the expected behavior of `repository.GetItems(true)` returns an ordered list of items, then test that. But don't test that `items.OrderBy(x => x, new YourComparer())` does indeed sort the list. However, do unit test that `YourComparer` does indeed compare correctly.

Comment: are you absolutely certain it will always be ordered either ascending or descending?

Comment: Nope, that's something I want to test in two different scenarios

Comment: `l.OrderBy(e => e).SequenceEqual(l)` easiest way with LINQ

Comment: @Dennis What's wrong with Linq based answers though? I'm missing that. Anyway, I'll close the question.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: nothing wrong (except performance). Just haven't scrolled to non-LINQ ones.

Comment: @Martin I issued a merge request using a flag. I'd love to write a new community wiki question to provide an even better merge target (i.e. not "too localized" nor "too broad") that all answers can be migrated to. I'm fairly sure there's about a hundred _"How to check if a [list|collection|array] is sorted [ascending|descending|either way]"_ questions, all of them with their own answers repeating the approach shown here. We need more curation of such canconicals.

Comment: @PavelZagalsky Could you please unmark my answer? You can choose either TIm's or Martin's answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I have used your answer anyway because for my use it was sufficient enough. Thanks again

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you are using MSTest, you may want to take a look at [CollectionAssert.AreEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequal.aspx).

[Enumerable.SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) may be another useful API to use in an assertion.

In both cases you should prepare a list that holds the expected list in the expected order, and then compare that list to the result.

Here's an example:

```
var studyFeeds = Feeds.GetStudyFeeds(2120, DateTime.Today.AddDays(-200), 20);   
var expectedList = studyFeeds.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
Assert.IsTrue(expectedList.SequenceEqual(studyFeeds));
```

Comment: The question was: "is there's any way to test if a list is ordered by a property of the objects it contains.", So: a test that returns true if the sequence is ordered by a given property. NOT: if the sequence equals another sequence. I'd go for an extension method, possibly using `Enumerable.Aggregate`

Answer (score 62):

A .NET 4.0 way would be to use the [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(VS.100).aspx) method to zip the list with itself offset by one, which pairs each item with the subsequent item in the list. You can then check that the condition holds true for each pair, e.g.

```
var ordered = studyFeeds.Zip(studyFeeds.Skip(1), (a, b) => new { a, b })
                        .All(p => p.a.Date < p.b.Date);
```

If you're on an earlier version of the framework you can write your own Zip method without too much trouble, something like the following (argument validation and disposal of the enumerators if applicable is left to the reader):

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> selector)
{
    var e1 = first.GetEnumerator();
    var e2 = second.GetEnumerator();
    while (e1.MoveNext() & e2.MoveNext()) // one & is important
        yield return selector(e1.Current, e2.Current);
}
```

Comment: This will be more memory efficient than the other answers that use OrderBy().

Comment: This needs to be on top.

Comment: This can be simplified further so it uses only one lambda expression instead of two and gets rid of the anonymous type, improving readability. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32578647/533837). :)

Comment: One thing worth to fix is the condition which should be `<=` instead. Items with the same date which are next to each other in the collection don't make the order invalid.

Answer (score 39):

Nunit 2.5 introduced [CollectionOrderedContraint](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.5.8) and a nice syntax for verifying the order of a collection:

```
Assert.That(collection, Is.Ordered.By("PropertyName"));
```

No need to manually order and compare.

Comment: I like this, but at it's current state is very limited (can't order by multiple columns while setting acending/descending. :(

Comment: The functionality of Nunit has been extended. Assertions now allow the use of your own comparers, as you can see [in the manual](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Collection-Assert.html). Constraints support a number of settings, including the direction and choice of the desired property (multiple properties even).

Answer (score 27):

If your unit testing framework has helper methods to assert equality of collections, you should be able do something like this (NUnit flavored):

```
var sorted = studyFeeds.OrderBy(s => s.Date);
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(sorted.ToList(), studyFeeds.ToList());
```

The assert method works with any `IEnumerable`, but when both collections are of type `IList` or "array of something", the error message thrown when the assert fails will contain the index of the first out-of-place element.

Comment: +1. Nice. I've used NUnit for years and didn't know about this. Also just discovered FileAssert and StringAssert! Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't work :(. Error message:

Baischana.Components.Services.Test.StudyFeedsTest.GetStudyFeeds_IsOrderedByDate:
  Expected: <System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[Baischana.Components.StudyFeedItem,System.DateTime]>
  But was:  < <Baischana.Components.StudyFeedItem>, <Baischana.Components.StudyFeedItem>, <Baischana.Components.StudyFeedItem>, <Baischana.Components.StudyFeedItem>, <Baischana.Components.StudyFeedItem> >

Comment: Sorting a list is quite ineffective in terms of computational complexity.

Comment: +1 for CollectionAssert, I didn't know that. @el-pescado: that's true, but it's a unit test, not production code...

Comment: @Nicole: That is the error message you get when the assertion fails. Try to pass the assert method two objects of type IList (my answer is edited to do that), and it should give you another error message, containing the index of the first out-of-place element.

Answer (score 22):

The solutions posted involving sorting the list are expensive - determining if a list IS sorted can be done in O(N).  Here's an extension method which will check:

```
public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IList<T> list, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    if (list.Count > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (comparer.Compare(list[i - 1], list[i]) > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

A corresponding `IsOrderedDescending` could be implemented easily by changing `> 0` to `< 0`.

Comment: `>=` is wrong, it would return false on `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]`.  Modifying this to detect a reverse sort is trivial too.

Comment: So much better than an approach that sorts the data, (which makes my teeth itch).

Comment: You can't use `>` or any  operator to compare elements inside a generic method.

Comment: Works with `IList<String>` but not with `IList<T>` or even `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Indeed, I should've written that in VS rather than in the browser!  Updated with the same comparer method you used.

Comment: You don't even need lists or indexed access. You can do it on a simple IEnumerable.

Answer (score 14):

Greg Beech [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1940284/533837), although excellent, can be simplified further by performing the test in the Zip itself. So instead of:

```
var ordered = studyFeeds.Zip(studyFeeds.Skip(1), (a, b) => new { a, b })
                        .All(p => p.a.Date <= p.b.Date);
```

You can simply do:

```
var ordered = !studyFeeds.Zip(studyFeeds.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.Date <= b.Date)
                        .Contains(false);
```

Which saves you one lambda expression and one anonymous type.

(In my opinion removing the anonymous type also makes it easier to read.)

Comment: I find this version easier to read :
studyFeeds.Zip(studyFeeds.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.Date < b.Date)
                        .All(b => true);

Comment: Personally I can't say I perceive any clarity difference between testing that all is true versus testing if any is false, that extra lambda seems unnecessary to me, but whatever floats your boat I guess.

Comment: @StackHola I think you've got a typo: `(b => true)` will always return true ignoring if `b` is false or true and I think you meant `(b => b)`

Comment: @SteveCadwallader Yes you're right, can't edit back. Correct form is : studyFeeds.Zip(studyFeeds.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.Date < b.Date) .All(b => b);

Comment: Since it now reads as "All b" instead of "All true" I don't think it's easier to read at all. When you read `All(b => b)` you pause for a moment thinking about it to realize we are doing an "all true"-test, and then have to re-read the preceding part to see the actual condition we are testing.

Comment: One thing worth to fix is the condition which should be `<=` instead. Same values next to each other doesn't make the order invalid

Comment: This is great, and it can go a bit further too:  

`var ordered = !studyFeeds.Zip(studyFeeds.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.Date <= b.Date).Min();`

Comment: @RyanNaccarato What do you mean? You are doing a `Min` on an `IEnumerable<bool>`.

Comment: Yep!  The min value in a list of bools is `false (0)`, the max being `true (1)`.  So, `.Min()` will do the trick.

Comment: @RyanNaccarato Aha, well in that case you have a small bug: you need to remove the negation in front of "!studyFeeds..." since you swapped `Contains(false)` which is `true` if the list is unordered to `Min()` which is `false` if the list is unordered. You saved one more char. ;) ...However I'm not sure if `Min` over bool is smart enough to stop when it encounters the first false value or not. If it isn't smart enough to do that then the performance has degraded.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, no ```!``` needed.

Answer (score 9):

```
if(studyFeeds.Length < 2)
  return;

for(int i = 1; i < studyFeeds.Length;i++)  
 Assert.IsTrue(studyFeeds[i-1].Date > studyFeeds[i].Date);
```

`for` isn't dead just quite yet!

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
var list = items.ToList();
for(int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++) {
    Assert.IsTrue(yourComparer.Compare(list[i - 1], list[i]) <= 0);
}
```

where `yourComparer` is an instance of `YourComparer` which implements [`IComparer<YourBusinessObject>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3.aspx). This ensures that every element is less than the next element in the enumeration.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676178/simple-sort-verification-for-unit-testing-an-order-by

Comment: asserting is only good in Debug, it will tell you if the list is order, but wont do anything in a release, Assert is good for verification when something should always be true!

Answer (score 6):

You could use an extension method like this:

```
public static System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection? SortDirection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Comparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
    if (comparer == null) comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

    bool ascendingOrder = true; bool descendingOrder = true;
    using (var e = items.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (e.MoveNext())
        {
            T last = e.Current; // first item
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                int diff = comparer.Compare(last, e.Current);
                if (diff > 0)
                    ascendingOrder = false;
                else if (diff < 0)
                    descendingOrder = false;

                if (!ascendingOrder && !descendingOrder)
                    break;
                last = e.Current;
            }
        }
    }
    if (ascendingOrder)
        return System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    else if (descendingOrder)
        return System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending;
    else
        return null;
}
```

It enables to check if the sequence is sorted and also determines the direction:

```
var items = new[] { 3, 2, 1, 1, 0 };
var sort = items.SortDirection();
Console.WriteLine("Is sorted? {0}, Direction: {1}", sort.HasValue, sort);
//Is sorted? True, Direction: Descending
```

Comment: This iterates the input a lot more than I'd expect a self-contained LINQ function to.

Comment: @Rawling: because of `Any` and `First`. That doesn't iterate the sequence but only checks the first. If any of the items is not ordered it will stop enumeration and return `false`.

Comment: It still calls `GetEnumerable`. If that's expensive, and it can be, you're calling it three times more than you need to.

Comment: @Rawling: true, and the accepted answer is more elegant. But isn't `OrderBy` + `SequenceEqual` less efficient because it needs to order the whole sequence before it can start with `SequenceEqual` whereas my `foreach` can compare the order immediately? It also needs to process it twice to check both directions whereas my loop only needs one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Your answer is **a way** better than the accepted. But I would personally use implicit enumerator (`using (var e = items.GetEnumerator())` with `e.MoveNext()` and `e.Current`) to avoid `Any()`, 'Skip`, and `First`.

Comment: Tim, I agree yours is way better than the accepted, yes :)

Comment: @Rawling: I have edited my answer. One question: is an empty collection or one that contains only one item ordered or not? If it is, in which direction? The method above returns `Ascending`, is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

*Linq based answer is:*

You can use `SequenceEqual` method to check if the original and ordered one is same or not.

```
var isOrderedAscending = lJobsList.SequenceEqual(lJobsList.OrderBy(x => x));
var isOrderedDescending = lJobsList.SequenceEqual(lJobsList.OrderByDescending(x => x));
```

Don't forget to import `System.Linq` namespace.

***Additionally:***

I am repeating that this answer is Linq based, you can achieve more efficiency by creating your custom extension method.

Also, if somebody still wants to use Linq and check if the sequence both is ordered in ascending or descending order, then you can achieve a little bit more efficiency like that:

```
var orderedSequence = lJobsList.OrderBy(x => x)
                               .ToList();

var reversedOrderSequence = orderedSequence.AsEnumerable()
                                           .Reverse();

if (lJobsList.SequenceEqual(orderedSequence))
{
     // Ordered in ascending
}
else (lJobsList.SequenceEqual(reversedOrderSequence))
{
     // Ordered in descending
}
```

Comment: @PavelZagalsky Glad to help. But don't forget there exist other more efficient approachs which must be implemented by yourself.

Comment: @CodeCaster 1) Don't use such words `the most horrible approach`!!!. 2) I wrote in my answer that this is not the most efficient. But if the sequences are not big, then this solution may come handy in urgent moments. 3) The answer is right at the end! 4) Also I want to say that, don't think that I don't know to count iterations on my linq code. I know how Linq works. And have read all LINQ extension methods source codes. 5) Have a nice day.

Comment: @CodeCaster "Don't get offended if someone points out a flaw in your code" which I have mentioned already in my answer. It looks like that: You are trying to tell me that pen is a pen. We already know that.

Comment: You mention "Linq based" and "extension method", which have nothing to do with performance. Again, you could do yourself a great benefit by not getting offended so easily.

Comment: @CodeCaster Also, you have wrote that I was complaining. Yes. But my coplaining was about the braveness of the downoter. I was aware of that my answer is not the most efficient. But, the downvoter was not so brave to comment that to my answer. And you are very good to use  metaphoric phrases in your sentences.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have copied that from my answer : *I am repeating that this answer is Linq based, you can achieve more efficiency by creating your custom extension method.*. I mean custom extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: And I'll repeat, Linq and extension methods have nothing to do with performance.

Comment: @CodeCaster  I am speaking about built-in Linq methods! Your custom extension method about some special logic will be mor efficeient than using built-in multiple Linq methods. I am totally sure that, I know how such things work in .Net ;). So, have a nice day. This is my last comment. I will dlete the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I do it with Linq and I comparable, might not be the best but works for me and it's test framework independent.

So the call looks like this:

```
    myList.IsOrderedBy(a => a.StartDate)
```

This works for anything that implements IComparable, so numbers strings and anything that inherit from IComparable:

```
    public static bool IsOrderedBy<T, TProperty>(this List<T> list, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyExpression) where TProperty : IComparable<TProperty>
    {
        var member = (MemberExpression) propertyExpression.Body;
        var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo) member.Member;
        IComparable<TProperty> previousValue = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
        {
            var currentValue = (TProperty)propertyInfo.GetValue(list[i], null);
            if (previousValue == null)
            {
                previousValue = currentValue;
                continue;
            }

            if(previousValue.CompareTo(currentValue) > 0) return false;
            previousValue = currentValue;

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Hope this helps, took me ages to work this one out.

Answer (score 2):

Checking a sequence can have four different outcomes. `Same` means that all elements in the sequence are the same (or the sequence is empty):

```
enum Sort {
  Unsorted,
  Same,
  SortedAscending,
  SortedDescending
}
```

Here is a way to check the sorting of a sequence:

```
Sort GetSort<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IComparer<T> comparer = null) {
  if (source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
  if (comparer == null)
    comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

  using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
      return Sort.Same;
    Sort? result = null;
    var previousItem = enumerator.Current;
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
      var nextItem = enumerator.Current;
      var comparison = comparer.Compare(previousItem, nextItem);
      if (comparison < 0) {
        if (result == Sort.SortedDescending)
          return Sort.Unsorted;
        result = Sort.SortedAscending;
      }
      else if (comparison > 0) {
        if (result == Sort.SortedAscending)
          return Sort.Unsorted;
        result = Sort.SortedDescending;
      }
    }
    return result ?? Sort.Same;
  }
}
```

I'm using the enumerator directly instead of a `foreach` loop because I need to examine the elements of the sequence as pairs. It makes the code more complex but is also more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

One way or another you're going to have to walk the list and ensure that the items are in the order you want.  Since the item comparison is custom, you could look into creating a generic method for this and passing in a comparison function - the same way that sorting the list uses comparison functions.

Answer (score 0):

Something LINQ-y would be to use a separate sorted query...

```
var sorted = from item in items
 orderby item.Priority
 select item;

Assert.IsTrue(items.SequenceEquals(sorted));
```

Type inference means you'd need a

```
 where T : IHasPriority
```

However, if you have multiple items of the same priority, then for a unit test assertion you're probably best off just looping with the list index as Jason suggested.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676178/simple-sort-verification-for-unit-testing-an-order-by

Answer (score 0):

```
var studyFeeds = Feeds.GetStudyFeeds(2120, DateTime.Today.AddDays(-200), 20);
var orderedFeeds = studyFeeds.OrderBy(f => f.Date);

for (int i = 0; i < studyFeeds.Count; i++)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(orderedFeeds[i].Date, studyFeeds[i].Date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this, without sorting the list

```
    public static bool IsAscendingOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq) where T : IComparable
    {
        var seqArray = seq as T[] ?? seq.ToArray();
        return !seqArray.Where((e, i) =>
            i < seqArray.Count() - 1 &&
            e.CompareTo(seqArray.ElementAt(i + 1)) >= 0).Any();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more lightweight generic version. To test for descending order, change the >= 0 comparison to <= 0.

```
public static bool IsAscendingOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    var predecessor = default(T);
    var hasPredecessor = false;

    foreach(var x in seq)
    {
        if (hasPredecessor && predecessor.CompareTo(x) >= 0) return false;
        predecessor = x;
        hasPredecessor = true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Tests:

- new int[] { }.IsAscendingOrder() returns **true**
- new int[] { 1 }.IsAscendingOrder() returns **true**
- new int[] { 1,2 }.IsAscendingOrder() returns **true**
- new int[] { 1,2,0 }.IsAscendingOrder() returns **false**

Answer (score 0):

While AnorZaken's and Greg Beech's answers are very nice, as they don't require using an extension method, it can be good to avoid Zip() sometimes, as some enumerables can be expensive to enumerate in this way.

A solution can be found in Aggregate()

```
double[] score1 = new double[] { 12.2, 13.3, 5, 17.2, 2.2, 4.5 };
double[] score2 = new double[] { 2.2, 4.5, 5, 12.2, 13.3, 17.2 };

bool isordered1 = score1.Aggregate(double.MinValue,(accum,elem)=>elem>=accum?elem:double.MaxValue) < double.MaxValue;
bool isordered2 = score2.Aggregate(double.MinValue,(accum,elem)=>elem>=accum?elem:double.MaxValue) < double.MaxValue;

Console.WriteLine ("isordered1 {0}",isordered1);
Console.WriteLine ("isordered2 {0}",isordered2);
```

One thing a little ugly about the above solution, is the double less-than comparisons. Floating comparisons like this make me queasy as it is almost like a floating point equality comparison. But it seems to work for double here. Integer values would be fine, also.
The floating point comparison can be avoided by using nullable types, but then the code becomes a bit harder to read.

```
double[] score3 = new double[] { 12.2, 13.3, 5, 17.2, 2.2, 4.5 };
double[] score4 = new double[] { 2.2, 4.5, 5, 12.2, 13.3, 17.2 };

bool isordered3 = score3.Aggregate((double?)double.MinValue,(accum,elem)=>(elem>(accum??(double?)double.MaxValue).Value)?(double?)elem:(double?)null) !=null;
bool isordered4 = score4.Aggregate((double?)double.MinValue,(accum,elem)=>(elem>(accum??(double?)double.MaxValue).Value)?(double?)elem:(double?)null) !=null;

Console.WriteLine ("isordered3 {0}",isordered3);
Console.WriteLine ("isordered4 {0}",isordered4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ordered and an unordered version of the list first:

```
var asc = jobs.OrderBy(x => x);
var desc = jobs.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Now compare the original list with both:

```
if (jobs.SequenceEqual(asc) || jobs.SequenceEquals(desc)) // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda in extension:

```
public static bool IsAscending<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, T, int> compareTo) {
  var list = self as IList<T> ?? self.ToList();
  if (list.Count < 2) {
    return true;
  }
  T a = list[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++) {
    T b = list[i];
    if (compareTo(a, b) > 0) {
      return false;
    }
    a = b;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Using:

```
bool result1 = Enumerable.Range(2, 10).IsAscending((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
```

more:

```
var lst = new List<(int, string)> { (1, "b"), (2, "a"), (3, "s1"), (3, "s") };
bool result2 = lst.IsAscending((a, b) => {
  var cmp = a.Item1.CompareTo(b.Item1);
  if (cmp != 0) {
    return cmp;
  } else {
    return a.Item2.CompareTo(b.Item2);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.CollectionAssert.AreEqual(
  mylist.OrderBy((a) => a.SomeProperty).ToList(),
  mylist,
  "Not sorted.");
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing? Posting just code as an answer is not the best practice.

Answer (score -1):

All of the answers given are based on asserting items are in a given order, rather than a more general test (perhaps to avoid an unnecessary sort).

I use this to check if items are in a given order before committing to sort them:

```
public static bool All<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, Func<T, T, bool> function)
{
   if(values == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (values));
   if(function == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (function));
   using(IEnumerator<T> e = values.GetEnumerator())
   {
      if(e.MoveNext())
      {
         T left = e.Current;
         if(!e.MoveNext())
            return true;
         T right = e.Current;
         do
         {
            if(!function(left, right))
               return false;
            left = right;
            right = e.Current;
         }
         while(e.MoveNext());
      }
      return true;
   }
}

public static void AllExample()
{
   int[] items = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

   /// true if the elements appear in ascending order:

   items.All((a, b) => a <= b);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var expectedList = resultA.ToArray();
var actualList = resultB.ToArray();
var i = 0;
foreach (var item in expectedList)
{
     Assert.True(expectedList[i].id == actualList[i].id);
     i++;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a foreach loop if you don't intent to use the iteration variable? That doesn't make sense and you should probably be using a for loop instead.