# Sort a list alphabetically

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I have the following class:

```
class Detail
{
    public Detail()
    {
        _details = new List<string>();
    }
    public IList<string> Details { get { return _details; } }
    private readonly List<string> _details;
}
```

Currently I sort the class randomly using the following:

```
void ShuffleGenericList<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    //generate a Random instance
    var rnd = new Random();
    //get the count of items in the list
    var i = list.Count();
    //do we have a reference type or a value type
    T val = default(T);

    //we will loop through the list backwards
    while (i >= 1)
    {
        //decrement our counter
        i--;
        //grab the next random item from the list
        var nextIndex = rnd.Next(i, list.Count());
        val = list[nextIndex];
        //start swapping values
        list[nextIndex] = list[i];
        list[i] = val;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to sort the contents of details in alphabetic order.

So for example if the contents look like this:

```
[0] a
[1] d
[2] b
```

I want to be able to run this method and have them sorted into:

```
[0] a
[1] b
[2] d
```

Does anyone know of a simple way to do this? Note that the lists usually have less than ten entries in them. Can I do this with LINQ? Sorry but I am not very familiar with LINQ I have just heard a suggestion that I could use that.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can sort a list *in-place* just by calling [`List<T>.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort):

```
list.Sort();
```

That will use the natural ordering of elements, which is fine in your case.

EDIT: Note that in your code, you'd need

```
_details.Sort();
```

as the `Sort` method is only defined in `List<T>`, not `IList<T>`. If you need to sort it from the outside where you don't have access to it as a `List<T>` (you shouldn't cast it as the `List<T>` part is an implementation detail) you'll need to do a bit more work.

I don't *know* of any `IList<T>`-based in-place sorts in .NET, which is slightly odd now I come to think of it. `IList<T>` provides everything you'd need, so it *could* be written as an extension method. There are lots of quicksort implementations around if you want to use one of those.

If you don't care about a bit of inefficiency, you could always use:

```
public void Sort<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    List<T> tmp = new List<T>(list);
    tmp.Sort();
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i] = tmp[i];
    }
}
```

In other words, copy, sort in place, then copy the sorted list back.

---

You can use LINQ to create a *new* list which contains the original values but sorted:

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

It depends which behaviour you want. Note that your shuffle method isn't really ideal:

- Creating a new `Random` within the method runs into some of the problems [shown here](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Random)
- You can declare `val` inside the loop - you're not *using* that default value
- It's more idiomatic to use the `Count` property when you *know* you're working with an `IList<T>`
- To my mind, a `for` loop is simpler to understand than traversing the list backwards with a `while` loop

There are other implementations of shuffling with Fisher-Yates on Stack Overflow - search and you'll find one pretty quickly.

Comment: So if I wanted to sort the list you create above then would I just need to say: sortedList.Sort ?

Comment: I tried the Sort but can't get that to work.- My list looks like this: IList<string>  nD.  I tried nD.Sort() but it says: Can't resolve symbol 'Sort'.

Comment: @Mariko: Use `_details.Sort()` instead - as `_details` is declared as a `List<string>` rather than `IList<string>`. `Sort` is only declared on `List<T>`, not `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 37):

There are two ways:

Without LINQ: `yourList.Sort();`

With LINQ: `yourList.OrderBy(x => x).ToList()`

You will find more information in: https://www.dotnetperls.com/sort

Comment: @Dminox - My list looks like this: IList<string>  nD.  I tried nD.Sort() but it says: Can't resolve symbol 'Sort'.

Comment: @Mariko `Sort()` is a member of `List<T>` *not* `IList<T>`. You might consider switching to the former (unless you expect to be working with different `IList<T>` implementations.)

Answer (score 28):

Another way

```
_details.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.CompareTo(s2));
```

Comment: This one has the advantage of adapting to **sorting any object by one  of it's properties**.

Comment: +1 I combined this with [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32578647/1836461) to unit/integration test sorting order of a string.

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to use `OrderBy` in LINQ...

```
var sortedItems = myList.OrderBy(s => s);
```

Comment: Note: that returns `IEnumerable<T>` and is not in-place sort

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with `List<T>.Sort()`?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort#overloads

Comment: @goril - I would like to use this but I get an error. This is what I added to the other comment. Hope you can help - My list looks like this: IList<string>  nD.  I tried nD.Sort() but it says: Can't resolve symbol 'Sort'.

Comment: @Mariko: you use interface IList<T> which does not contain Sort method. Sort List<T> variable directly. In other words you can sort `_details` from your example but not `Details`