# Sorting an array of n people alphabetically

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, .net-core

I know stackoverflow has many questions like this one, but it appears that none of them are actually a solution to this.

I had a coding interview three weeks ago and one of the questions been "How do you sort an array of n people by their name in an alphabetical order ?" problem is not the answer, but `Array.Sort()` function was not allowed.

First thing that came in my mind was creating an array of chars of which i i can attempt to get the first char of each string from that array and store them in `char[]`, then a nested loop to actually do the job, but after a few minutes passed this has no sense and it was or i think a wrong approach by me.

Looking in the Internet the algo that i am looking for is the Quicksort method, but this totally looks something overcomplicated, do i actually need to learn about Quicksort and replicate the algo myself or there is something less complicated that orders that array of people alphabetically ?

Comment: The _practical_ solution is not to worry about the algorithm and use Linq's `.Sort()` method. Is there something more specific you need than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965337/sort-a-list-alphabetically)?

Comment: Exchange sort and bubble sort are really simple, if you need something you can write on the fly

Comment: @NigelBess oh .... exactly what i was looking for... thank you.. i will now never forget about the bubble sort, ironically i was using it to sort integers too

Comment: @theo Im glad that helped you out. I re-posted my comment as an answer to farm some sweet reputation points. Dont forget to upvote and select a best answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Exchange Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Exchange_sort) and [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Bubble_sort) are two quite simple sorting algorithms that can be written on the fly.