# C# -- Get, then compare values from JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I need to extract values from a JSON string so I can compare them. 
I only need to verify that they are in order (ascending/descending). 
I was going to check the first and second 'choices' and compare. 
I don't anything more advanced.

EDIT/UPDATE:
How could I use wildcards (*) in this type of query to skip having each segment?

```
               string one = (string)o[this.Context[*WILDCARD*]["cid1"]].ToString();


           /* this works, but has too many []
           string one = (string)o[this.Context["partner"]]
               [this.Context["campaign"]]
               [this.Context["segment1"]]
               [this.Context["segment2"]]
               [this.Context["qid2"]]
               ["community"]
               [this.Context["cid1"]].ToString();
           */


{
  "partner": {
    "campaign": {
      "round1": {
        "round2": {
          "def123": {
            "community": {
              "choicec": 28
            },
            "user": {
              "choice": "choicec",
              "writeDateUTC": "2015-06-15T17:21:59Z"
            }
          }
        },
        "abc321": {
          "community": {
            "choicec": 33
          },
          "user": {
            "choice": "choicec",
            "writeDateUTC": "2015-06-15T17:21:59Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a cool project! What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Ive tried using LINQ, Jtoken, Jpath, and others and all fail or return empty. So im reaching out to the community

Comment: Try this with JSON.NET (you'll need `using Newtonsoft.Json` after you've added the Nuget package): `dynamic d = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(yourJsonString);` then use `d.partner.campaign.round1.def123.community.choicec` to access the choice number.

Comment: why `dynamic` ? there must have been a concrete calss.

Comment: There's no `"cid1"` property in your JSON.  Just to confirm, you want to compare the values of the `"choicec": 28` and `"choicec": 33` properties to check if they're in order?

Comment: "choicec" is fed in by context variables. But you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having some difficulty may be that the two `"choicec"` properties are not at the same depth in the JSON hierarchy.  The first is underneath `"round2"` while the second is not.  Thus straightforward indexing will not work.

Assuming that you are able to use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), your options are:

1. Use [`Descendants`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Descendants.htm) to look for *all* properties named `"choicec"` and check if they are ordered:

   ```
       var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
       bool inOrder = obj.Descendants()
           .OfType<JProperty>()
           .Where(p => p.Name == "choicec")
           .Select(p => (int)p.Value)
           .IsOrdered();
   ```
2. Use [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) with [JsonPath wildcards](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to restrict the search to a portion of your JSON, if there happen to be other properties named `"choicec"` in your hierarchy that are not relevant to the query:

   ```
       // Find all properties named "choicec" under "community" recursively under "campaign" under "partner".
       bool inOrder = obj.SelectTokens("partner.campaign..community.choicec")
           .Select(o => (int)o)
           .IsOrdered();
   ```

   Here `..` is a wildcard meaning "recursive descent".

Using the following `IsOrdered` extension from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786101/native-c-sharp-support-for-checking-if-an-ienumerable-is-sorted) by [Mikkel R. Lund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234910/mikkel-r-lund):

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    // Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786101/native-c-sharp-support-for-checking-if-an-ienumerable-is-sorted
    public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;

        using (var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var previous = enumerator.Current;

                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var current = enumerator.Current;

                    if (comparer.Compare(previous, current) > 0)
                        return false;

                    previous = current;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thorough and helpful.