# How to check if contents of a List<String> is alphabetical

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to check if the List I have is in Alphabetical Ascending or Descending order. How do I go about with it?

I have this Jobs list that has like 5,6 strings inside.

```
List<String> lJobsList = new List<String>();
```

I'd like to have a boolean value whether the list is sorted in Asc or Desc order.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: @Dennis why did you reopen? [How to check if a list is ordered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940214/how-to-check-if-a-list-is-ordered) _is_ an exact dupe of this. This is the problem with this site, nobody cares to update canonicals, just dump the same answers over and over again...

Comment: IMO, closing this question as duplicate isn't correct, because posted answers are LINQ-based

Comment: The duplicate question is slightly different. This question is about how to determine if the list is either in ascending or descending order. The linked question is only about how determine if a list is in ascending order. There are ways to solve the problem in this question without simply using the linked solution two times (one with the reverse order).