# Need help sorting text file in C#

Tags: c#

I dont need to sort the text file I just need to be able to tell if the text file is in alphabetical order or not. like true or false
The text file is a list of words like:

apple
dog
cat
bed
for example this text above would come out as false because it is not in order

Comment: In order to determine whether a collection is sorted, you have to compare it to the same collection, but then sorted. You can implement this by comparing whether the current element would come before or after the previous element. See for example [How to check if a list is ordered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940214/how-to-check-if-a-list-is-ordered), where most approaches go for the former, full-blown, slow approach. That being said, this question reads like "give me the code", which is not how this site works. Read the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: This reads a lot like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is just:

1. Read the file
2. While not end of file,
3. if current line is empty, skip.
4. else, check current line lexicographically and see if it is smaller than the previous line.
5. if yes, return false (file is not ordered)
6. if no, continue the process.
7. When reached end of file, return true (file is ordered)

Comment: Im still very new to programming and wouldnt know what code to use in order to check line lexicographically. Can you just write up mock code or something. That would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @MikeBeccaris All you need is just String.compare. E.g.: `String.compare(s1, s2, true)`. You can read up here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: its not allowing me to compare the strings because it says it cannot compare System.IO with boolean. I am trying to compare text files in my bin/debug folder

Comment: I am very sure you have used it wrongly. Look at the method signature and the parameter types in the documentation.

Comment: StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Words.txt");
            StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader("Words2.txt");

            var lineCount = File.ReadLines("Words.txt").Count();

            String.Compare(sr, sr2, true);
this is what i have so far

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.StreamReader' to 'string'

this is the error i get

Comment: Your sr and sr2 need to be datatype: String. This is the basics of programming. Nothing to do with whether it works or not. Did you even read the documentation before asking me? We are not here to teach basic programming. I've already answered your question to the fullest. It seems that you are not even appreciative. That's all I am going to help.