# Know if order is changed after calling List.Sort()?

Tags: c#

For example, if a `List` contains `{1,2,3,4,5}`, calling `Sort()` will not change anything. But if a list contains `{1,2,4,3,5}`, then calling `Sort()` will change the order.

Is there any way to know if `Sort()` has changed anything? The method returns `void`.

**P.S.**
Actually, I tested this before posting this question. The idea was that `x` is an item currently before `y`, so if it needs to return a negative value, a swapping occurs. Unfortunately, it did not work... but why?

```
class IntComp : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        var result = x - y;
        if (result < 0)
            _IsChanged = true;
        return result;
    }

    private bool _IsChanged = false;
    public bool IsChanged()
    {
        var result = _IsChanged;
        _IsChanged = false;
        return result;
    }
}

var list = new List<int>() {};
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    list.Add(r.Next());
}

var comparer = new IntComp();
Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
w.Start();
list.Sort(comparer);
w.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(comparer.IsChanged() + ", " + w.Elapsed);
w.Restart();
list.Sort(comparer);
w.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(comparer.IsChanged() + ", " + w.Elapsed);
```

Comment: I am interested to know... why do you want to know?

Comment: If the order has not changed, I do not have to update the UI.

Comment: Then follow the answer that suggests you detect whether it's sorted before even sorting it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not compare the original list with the sorted one?

```
var tmp = new List<MyType>(myList);
list.Sort();

if(tmp.SequenceEquals(list))
{
    // both lists are equals so your list wasn´t modified by Sort
}
```

[`SequenceEquals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) will check if your two lists have the same elements in *the exact same order*.

EDIT: You could also write a simple method iterating your list and check if all elements are greater their ancestor. This should be the fasted way and avoids unnecessary iterations and copies of your list:

```
public bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) where T: IComparable
{
    for(int i = 1; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        if(myList[i - 1].CompareTo(myList[i]) == 1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there was an efficient way that this. This requires creating a new list and O(n) comparisons. Internally there must be a point where swapping occurs, and Sort() could monitor that and provide a way to know if it chaged anything. But since there seems to be no such thing, I will go this way.

Comment: @DamnVegetables You could read past this answer, if you actually want a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep only the original list in memory, what you can do is first check whether the list [is sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940214/how-to-check-if-a-list-is-ordered) in the first place. If it is, no need for sorting and so it has not changed; if it is not sorted, you can sort it and then you know for sure it has changed.

With this, you don't have to create a clone of the list which is used to compare later, so this saves you some memory.

Comment: You don´t get any memory because *checking if a list is sorted* will also sort the list by iterating it completely.

Comment: @Fran In the example, IsOrdered function takes only one list. You don't need two...

Comment: @Fran You don't compare the list to any other list.  You compare the items in the list with each other.  The answer also in no way requires even following the link to get the answer; saying it's a link only answer is absurd on its face.  There is clearly content in the answer beyond the link.

Comment: @Servy - IMHO The fact that the linked SO post has several answer and L-Four seems to be referring to a very specific answer not being the accepted one makes this confusing IMHO as that is what I assumed was being referred to. At least the not link only answer should have linked to the answer referred to or at least copy the code itself. This is just my opinion though...on it's face..I guess :(

Comment: @Fran Like I said, there's no need (or reason, really) to even follow the link.  The answer answers the question perfectly fine entirely on its own, and just happens to provide a supplemental link, if you would like more.