# Checking if a string of numbers is sorted C# in an if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, math, numbers

I'm trying to figure out how to write an if statement in C# that basically does this

```
string myString = "1234";  
if( myString is sorted)
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
else
    {
       // Do some other stuff
    }
```

Comment: whats the sort criteria?

Comment: Do you need to check only ascending order 1234 or descending order 4321 also means that string is sorted?

Comment: Are the digits only 0-9?  Or can there be other digits in there?

Comment: Since string is sequence of characters any answer to https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+if+sequence+is+ordered would work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940214/how-to-check-if-a-list-is-ordered looks like good duplicate (at least all current answers are covered there). If this duplicate does not solve your assignment - make sure to [edit] post with complete list of requirements and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to check would be to simply treat the string as a collection of `chars` and use the `System.Linq` extension `OrderBy()`. Note that the code below will throw an exception if one if the characters is not an integer:

```
var input = "1234";
var orderedInput = string.Join("", input.OrderBy(i => int.Parse(i.ToString())));

if (input == orderedInput)
{
    Console.WriteLine("it's sorted.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("it's not sorted");
}
```

If you want to allow non-numeric characters, you can use string sorting (which will sort by numeric then alphabetic), you can use:

```
var orderedInput = string.Join("", input.OrderBy(i => i.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid parsing, sorting and creating new string - zip string with itself shifted by one character, and then just check that characters placed in ascending order:

```
var ordered = myString.Zip(myString.Skip(1), (a, b) => a <= b).All(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to Simplify 'Rufus L' answer to help Ian Shirley. I tried to be instructive. I know that sort can be relative to culture matters but I want to explain it simple.

```
string myString = "12343";
var sortedChar = myString.ToCharArray().ToList(); //we convert string to character

            sortedChar.Sort(); //this two lines is equivalent to OrderBy

            string sortedString =string.Join("",sortedChar);//this code concat the character or string together with specified string(here "")
            if (sortedString == myString)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("it's sorted.");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("it's not sorted.");

            }
```

Comment: Nice. FWIW, you don't need the `ToCharArray().` part.