# Check List order is wrong or right , How to make code clear

Tags: c#

I want to check list order is right or worng , And my solution be here.
it worked , But it look dirty & stupid , Have any better soultion can do that ?

I add two example to explain is case .

```
public enum HI
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void TestOroder()
    {
        // check hiList order ----> A >B >C
        List<HI> hiList = new List<HI>() { HI.A, HI.B, HI.B, HI.B, HI.C , HI.C , HI.C };

        //right
        bool isRight = FindWorngOrder(hiList);

        // check hiList order ----> A >B >C
        List<HI> hiList2 = new List<HI>() { HI.A, HI.B, HI.C, HI.A ,HI.B, HI.B, HI.C };
        //worng
        bool isRight2 = FindWorngOrder(hiList);
    }

    public bool FindWorngOrder(List<HI> hiList)
    {
        bool haveWorngOrder;
        for (int i = 0; i < hiList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            HI current = hiList[i];
            HI next = hiList[i + 1];

            if (current == HI.C && next == HI.A ||
                current == HI.C && next == HI.B)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (current == HI.C && next == HI.B)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show at least 6 inputs which are in the **right** order and at least 6 which **are not** so we can understand what you mean.

Comment: @mjwills I edited my quesion :)

Comment: `OrderBy` to sort and `SequenceEqual` to compare it.

Comment: It is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1940284/59081).

Comment: Thank you all , I did by @mjwills solution well !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a list is ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940214/how-to-check-if-a-list-is-ordered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using:

```
public bool IsInTheSamerOrder(IEnumerable<HI> hiList)
{
    return hiList.SequenceEqual(hiList.OrderBy(z => z));
}
```

It is similar to your answer, but slightly shorter and doesn't need the explicit `List`.

Answer (score 0):

by @mjwills answer

```
public bool FindWorngOrder(List<HI> hiList)
    {
        List<HI> orderd = hiList.ToList();
        orderd.Sort();

        return orderd.SequenceEqual(hiList);
    }
```