# Checking for consecutive numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to implement a method for checking consecutive numbers in `C#`.
Given an integer list of `n` elements, it should return true/false if the numbers are consecutive.
So for example, `12345, 45678, 54321` would all be `true`.
And `435276, 243516, 974264` would be `false`.

My code seems to be performing as expected. But it's missing the end element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (inputList[i] < inputList[i + 1])
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{inputList[i]} is consecutive when compared to {inputList[i + 1]}");
        consecutiveCheck = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{inputList[i]} is not consecutive when compared to {inputList[i + 1]}");
        consecutiveCheck = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: These are not consecutive numbers, but increasing numbers.

Comment: What do you mean missing the end element? For which input does it fail and how?

Comment: Duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940214/how-to-check-if-a-list-is-ordered

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wEPqLS What specifically is the issue with your code @Keva161? It seems to work fine. `But it's missing the end element.` Sure, the code is only giving two lines of output but that is expected. If you have three values then you have two comparisons.

Comment: Your code isn't guaranteed to output all elements to the console when consecutiveCheck is set to false, because the loop terminates due to the break statement.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You mean you are checking if they are increasing:

```
bool inc = true;
for (int i = 1; i < inputList.Count; i++)
{
    if (inputList[i] < inputList[i - 1])
    {
       inc=false;
       break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"List has consecutive numbers: {(inc?"yes":"no")}");
```

Comment: My point is, this does not solve the problem. (I actually believe there is no problem) (PS. I did not downvote though)

Comment: Read the question again, there is not.

Comment: @JessedeWit, "Given an integer list of n elements, it should return true/false"...

Comment: Yes, your code will work, but so will the TO's code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do it:

```
int[] inputList = new [] { 12345, 45678, 54321 };

bool all_increasing = inputList.Zip(inputList.Skip(1), (x0, x1) => x1 > x0).All(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are Consecutive numbers

**It is series of number which have equal distance.**

**Example of Consecutive numbers**
1,2,3,4,5
1,3,5,7,9

**Example of NO Consecutive numbers**
1,2,4,8,11
1,3,6,10,11

```
            
            int diff = 0;
            
            for (var i = 0; i < numbersInput.Length-1; i++)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    diff = numbersInput[i + 1] - numbersInput[i];
                }
                else if(numbersInput[i] + diff != numbersInput[i+1])
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }

            return true;
```

Answer (score -3):

This code will work :

```
    private static bool isConsecutive(int[] list)
    {
        switch (list.Length)
        {
            case 0:
                throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be an empty collection.", nameof(list));
            case 1:
                throw new ArgumentException("This collection contains only one element.", nameof(list));
        }

        int direction = list[1]-list[0];

        for (var index = 0; index < list.Length; index++)
        {
            int nextIndex = index + 1;

            if (nextIndex >= list.Length)
            {
                continue;
            }

            int diff = list[nextIndex] - list[index];


            if (diff != direction)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This will return true for [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2], and false for [1,3,5,7].

Comment: Now I think it's fine

Comment: This will work for [1,3,5,7], but will fail for [1,3,5,8], since the `diff` is not equal to the `direction` (`3 != 2`).

Comment: Yes sure because this is what consecutive numbers is https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consecutive_integer

Comment: Quoting from the question: _12345, 45678, 54321 would all be true. And 435276, 243516, 974264 would be false_